# AVPlayer on ios Objective C app does not play video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, xib

Hi I have an iOS Objective-C app which does not use Storyboards (It uses XIB files)

I want to add a splash screen to play a video so I added a new Coca Touch Class derived from UIViewController (And ticked 'Also create XIB file).

I have swapped this class as my new main screen and it loads properly but does not play the video.  I have added the AVFoundation framework etc so that is not an issue.

Here is my code.

**.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VideoIntroViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

static const float PLAYER_VOLUME = 0.0;

@interface VideoIntroViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playerView;

@end

@implementation VideoIntroViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createVideoPlayer];
}

- (void)createVideoPlayer
 {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.player.volume = PLAYER_VOLUME;

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [self.player play];
}
```

The screen launched but no video plays.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: What debugging have you done? What actually happens at runtime in the `createVideoPlayer` method? What's the actual frame you assign to `playerLayer.frame`? Is anything `nil`?

Comment: I am debugging in the simulator, nothing is null in createVideoPlayer. I see in the debug output window lots of AQDefaultDevice skipping inputstream 0 0 0x0 messages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

CALayer *superlayer = self.playerView.layer;
self.player.volume = 1.0;

AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;// you can also use AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect to clip video to view's bound
playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;

[superlayer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[self.player play];
```

I have checked it for some other video file and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my main XIB file I did not have a View control placed on it.
When I placed a View Control and then CTL+Right clicked and connected it to my playerView it then played the video.